# Can I specify billing usage limits on Google Map's Dynamic API calls

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Based on new Pricing of Google Maps API, can I specify API limit for Map's Dynamic API so that I can keep my users not exceeding the monthly free limit. My app is a free app so I need this. I am fine if the API functionality degrades after crossing the limit.

Comment: It looks like you are asking about Google Maps Android SDK. Note that Dynamic Maps in Android SDK are free of charge according to the price sheet: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/. Mobile Native Dynamic Maps is unlimited with 0$ price. Do you use something else apart from native maps?

Comment: you are right, I am using Google Maps Android SDK. I enabled this API from console application and it Maps worked on my phone. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

User xomena comment answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are different status codes for exceeding your limit.you need to handle status codes.if in the status code you will get "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT".its means you are exceeding the limit.Like this you can handle.